# MySQL data migration

Tags: mysql, migration, data-migration, database-migration

I have a MySQL database with some data.

I have to migrate this data between databases with almost the same tables, but different with table and field names.

The data is the same on both databases, only the table names (and some field name/type) change. But they aren't exactly the same structure.. I removed some fields from tables, and moved fields to another table.

How can I achieve this without making a script to iterate over every record and insert them on the new database? Any tool?

Comment: How about you just INSERT .. SELECT FROM? `insert into newtable (newcol1, newcol2, newcol3) select from oldtable (oldcola, oldcolb, oldcolc).` You can add or omit columns, do alter-tables to change column types...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [mysql_dump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to produce a .sql file which has all the queries necessary to recreate a database and its contents. You can then edit this .sql file to change table/field names to reflect the new DB's setup.

Comment: They aren't exactly the same structure.. I removed some fields from tables, and moved fields to another table.

Comment: Should have mentioned that in your question. You just said you'd changed table and field names, not rearranged structures.